# Query to return users paired with their most viewed director in a movie rental DB

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming a DB with two tables structured like so:

Movies (Movie_ID, Director)

Rentals (CustomerID, Movie_ID)

I need to return users paired with the name of the director whose movies they have rented the most. I've figured out how to do it in MySQL but can't figure out the right syntax to get it to work in Oracle.

**Working MySQL:**

```
SELECT x.CustomerID, x.Director
  FROM (SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
          FROM Rentals AS r
          JOIN Movies AS m
            ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
       ) x
  JOIN (SELECT x.CustomerID, MAX(x.DirectorCount) AS MaxDirectorCount
          FROM (SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
                  FROM Rentals AS r
                  JOIN Movies AS m
                    ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
                 GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
               ) x
         GROUP BY x.CustomerID
       ) y
    ON x.CustomerID = y.CustomerID AND x.DirectorCount = y.MaxDirectorCount
```

**Non Fuctioning Oracle:**

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
          FROM Rentals AS r
          JOIN Movies AS m
            ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
       )
WITH y AS (
                SELECT x.CustomerID, MAX(x.DirectorCount) AS MaxDirectorCount
          FROM (SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
                  FROM Rentals AS r
                  JOIN Movies AS m
                    ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
                 GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
               )
         GROUP BY x.CustomerID
      ) 
SELECT x.CustomerID, x.Director
JOIN
ON x.CustomerID = y.CustomerID AND x.DirectorCount = y.MaxDirectorCount
```

Comment: Don't see anything that shouldn't work on Oracle in your mysql query. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I get "ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"
which leads me to believe there's some sort of syntax that doesn't work in Oracle but works in mysql.

Comment: remove AS for table aliases: FROM Rentals r
                  JOIN Movies m

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting 'ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00904: "M"."MOVIE_ID": invalid identifier'. I also made a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3412a/8) and it's spitting out the same error.

Comment: Oracle does NOT like use of quoted  "column_names"  in fact using UPPERCASE columns names is still the best bet. Try this fiddle instead. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9c28/6 I do wish SQLFiddle would stop using quotes in the DDL

Comment: Looks like removing AS and not using double quoted column names works.

Comment: Also Oracle `with` clauses are comma-separated - you don't repeat the `with` keyword. Also you are missing a `from` clause and the table/view name after `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table aliases in Oracle are specified without AS.

```
SELECT x.CustomerID, x.Director
  FROM (SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
          FROM Rentals r
          JOIN Movies  m
            ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
         GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
       ) x
  JOIN (SELECT x.CustomerID, MAX(x.DirectorCount) AS MaxDirectorCount
          FROM (SELECT r.CustomerID, m.Director, COUNT(*) AS DirectorCount
                  FROM Rentals r
                  JOIN Movies m
                    ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
                 GROUP BY r.CustomerID, m.Director
               ) x
         GROUP BY x.CustomerID
       ) y
    ON x.CustomerID = y.CustomerID AND x.DirectorCount = y.MaxDirectorCount
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by using a window function to calculate the max count per customer, then filtering by that.

```
SELECT
       CustomerID
     , Director
     , directorcount
FROM (
    SELECT
          r.CustomerID
        , m.Director
        , COUNT(*) AS directorcount
        , max(COUNT(*)) over(partition by CustomerID) max_count
    FROM Rentals r
    JOIN Movies m ON r.Movie_ID = m.Movie_ID
    GROUP BY
          r.CustomerID
        , m.Director
    ) d
WHERE directorcount = max_count
```

- Already mentioned your Oracle query failed because of "AS" when declaring table aliases.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution. The only reason for the original query to be so complicated is that MySQL still lacks standard SQL window functions such as `MAX OVER` or `RANK`. Oracle does not, so why stick with the workaround!

Comment: Oh I do understand, but one day they will be available when version 8 gets released. Just remeber to avoid as for table aliases... i typically dont use them because of Oracle's inabiliry to tolerate them